Is there a way to make the shorthand { ...[ {...}, {...} ] } work?
So I ran into an interesting error. I though this would surely work, but looks like I might have hit an edge case in the ES6 syntax. Basically, I have an array of objects that I want to merge - with the later items in the array taking precedence over the prior. So, for instance, let us define a simple array of objects like so:
const arr = [ { a: 42, b: 69 }, { b: "hi", c: "bye" }, { c: NaN} ];

When I merge the objects in the array, I expect the result: { a: 42, b: "hi", c: Nan }
So what I wanted to do was this: { ...arr }
To my surprise, this does not work! (At least not in Firefox): Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '...'
Now, you can use the old school method and get the expected result: Object.assign({}, ...arr)
However, it is kind of bugging me that the new ES6 spread operator doesn't work here. Have I messed up the syntax somehow? Or is the ability to spread an array into an object simply not supported?

You did make an understandable mistake in the syntax – use parentheses to stop it from being treated as a block. And if Object.assign({}, arr) (edit: like you originally had) worked, ({...arr}) would too – but it doesn’t. No, you can’t achieve this for an arbitrary array with just the spread syntax.

@Ry- A yes I see what you mean about putting the parentheses around it. However, while I do get an object with the parentheses, the value isn't the same as what you'd get from using the old school Object.assign({}, ...arr) method

Because it does the equivalent of Object.assign({}, arr), like it always does. This is kind of like asking why you can’t sum an array with 0 + arr.

Fair enough. Seems this is one instance where we need to stick to the more verbose, old school method

calling it the old school method suggests there is a new method that achieves the same thing - but there isn't - so, technically, this is one instance where you use a method that actually does what you need it to do to achieve the desired result

@JaromandaX it is considered old school; standard lint rules and such have for quite a while flagged the method instructing you to use the new spread operator instead. Of course, that’s not to say there are t valid use cases, as above demonstrates. However, there’s no doubt the spread operator is much more succinct and thus preferable in general

It’s considered old-school for the use cases replaced by newer language features, which don’t include this one. Like how function () { … }.bind(this) is an old-school way to achieve lexical this compared to an arrow function, but bind is not obsolete. Lint rules that don’t detect the difference are buggy.
